# Can't redirect from login page to index page, when using Bootstrap login. Same system works on my other website, but not on this one

Tags: javascript, html

I've made two nearly the same webpages, but one uses bootstrap, the other one doesn't. The webpage without bootstrap works fine, it redirects me to my desired link. Now the other webpage that includes bootstrap runs fine, up until it has to redirect me to my index.html. Every other thing in my function works expect window.location.

```
<section class="container-fluid bg">
<section class="row justify-content-center">
<section class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"> 
<form class="form-container">
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Vasa E-Mail Adresa:</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
</div>
<div class="mb-3">
<label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Vas Password:</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">
</div>
<div class="mb-3 form-check">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="login()">Prihvati</button>
</form>
</form>
</section>
</section>
</section>
<script>
function login() {
var uname = document.getElementById("email").value;
var pwd = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
if (uname == '') {
    alert("Please enter your E-Mail.");
}
else if (pwd == '') {
    alert("Enter your Password");
}
else if (!filter.test(uname)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid E-Mail.");
}
else if (pwd.length < 4 || pwd.length > 20) {
    alert("Password must have between 4 and 20 characters.");
}
else {
    alert('Thank You for logging in and you will be redirected to the Web Page');
    window.location = "index.html";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: You aren't preventing the default form submit process. After the invalid alerts the form will reload current page as a result

Comment: So is there any way for me to fix it, or must i change the whole code? Sorry for stupid questions, I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: No. Do some research into how to prevent form submit with javascript